# How do I make a new line while returning a string?

Tags: python

I'm doing a class/object exercise in python and everything is working fine apart from this one line. So Im wondering if anyone has a solution to this

Tried a lot of variations with '\n' but none of them worked as expected

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'Account owner:   {self.owner}\nAccount balance:    ${self.balance}'
```

Expected it to be returned in 2 lines but it just keeps coming back like this 'Account owner:    Jose\nAccount balance:    $100'

Ty all in advance!

Comment: How is `__str__()` being called?

Comment: @noddy do you mean in the console? I just figured I was calling it wrong all the time,should have used print command instead of the str one to display it properly.

Comment: I was figuring it was likely what @Loocid answered below. If you provide your usage of a function and its context, it will aid others in better answering your question. Glad you got it solved!

Comment: Noted, will do next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you're using `__str__`. What you have done is correct however `\n` is only interpreted as a newline when you are writing it to something, be it the console or a file.

Example:

```
>>> a = "a\nb"
>>> a
'a\nb'
>>> print(a)
a
b
```

Comment: Ty, that explained it well and now I know I had to call it in the console with print command and not with str command... Cheers mate! Will accept it as an answer in 5 min! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Account owner: {}\nAccount balance: ${}".format(self.owner,self.balance)
```

Comment: How is this different from what they posted other than `format()` vs using an f-string?